# Treat (some) valgrind warnings as errors?

Tags: c++, valgrind

Is it possible to change some valgrind warnings into errors?

In particular, I want to turn the `probably lost` warning into an error.

In the valgrind manual I found only information about how to suppress warnings.

Is there a way to do what I want?

Comment: You can treat all valgrind warnings as errors.

Answer (score 1):

Since valgrind release 3.9, you can use the below command line options
to better control what leak to reports, and what leaks to consider as errors.

```
   --show-leak-kinds=kind1,kind2,.. which leak kinds to show?
                                            [definite,possible]
   --errors-for-leak-kinds=kind1,kind2,..  which leak kinds are errors?
                                            [definite,possible]
```